# adding multiple locales create huge size swf

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a simple flex (flex builder3) app with localized text. I need to add multiple locales to it. With two locales file size was around 500KB and now i have added 4 more locales and the size has gone upto 7MB.

Am I doing anything wrong here?
Is there any solution to reduce the file size?

Thanks for any help!

Using RSL is also not helpful.

Comment: locales are compiled and included in your swf. Except you want to do some kind of custom external loading/parsing of the pairs key/value for all your localized content, this will increase each time you add new locales.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adrian. This seems odd. Does this mean there is no way this can be use for multiple locales? Is there any way to add locale files as external libraries or something?

Comment: You can compile the locale swfs separately and load them at run time. Your app's startup code will have to detect the locale (from browser, shared object, cookie, etc) and load the proper locale SWF. I've seen it work quite well.

Comment: As Sunil D. wrote, you can do this as well, but it is not so easy to implement. If He can provide you with some good way (tutorial) to do it then this is the way to go.

Comment: thanks for showing some light there Sunil. This seems possible solution. And as Adrian said can you please provide any link for related tutorial? That will be much helpful, thanks!

Comment: @trupti take a look at these two articles from Adobe. The [first](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_localization_pt1.html) covers stuff you've probably already implemented. The [second](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-localization-pt2.html) discusses how to compile the resource bundles separately and load them at run time.

Comment: thanks Sunil. I will check the links.